# Virtual Keyboard of the MathLive library

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using the mathlive library and reactjs in my project which is a math-text-editor and it is using the original style of the package so I am trying to override it.

[image: the button style when inspecting]

When I hover on this button;

[image: the button in the DOM]

that expression saying `Toggle Virtual Keyboard` appears but I don't want. When inspecting this, it appears that the button has an after element on hover that have those properties, when I commented the first one **(the content property)** the expression disappears, but I could not select it or remove it in my css file even though I tried all the ways like content:'' and display:`none` as well as all:unset but in vain. Is there a way to remove the after element at all or at least override the content property to none?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not about the code because it is in the package already and I have no control over it!

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/guides/virtual-keyboards/#controlling-the-virtual-toggle-visibility) documentation:

```css
math-field::part(virtual-keyboard-toggle)::after {
  display: none;
}
```